# Как правильно настроить зависимости C# при работе с гит

Tags: c#, git

Допустим у меня есть библиотека для работы с матрицами.

Когда я подключаю ее к другому проекту(А), то .dll файл копируется в папку debug.
При загрузке проекта (А) на gitHub папка "debug" не загружается и нужный .dll файл теряется.

Выходит, после скачивания этот проект будет невозможно собрать.
Как решается данная проблема?

Comment: для этого есть nuget

Comment: Я так понимаю, нужно в gitignore прописать правило, разрешающее сохранение определенной dll из определенной папки. Что-то вроде https://stackoverflow.com/a/2415885/5045688

Comment: Как вы подключаете dll к проекту? Кто и как копирует dll в папку debug? Почему вы думаете, что папка debug, release должна оказаться в git и зачем? Покажите ваш .gitignore, это штатный от студии?

Answer (score 0):

В случае если вы создавали проект из Visual studio, которая автоматически сгенерировала вам файлы .gitignore и .gitattributes, то папки Debug и Release прописываются в исключения: их НЕ надо хранить в гите, они содержат уже скомпилированный проект и так не делают. Исходники отдельно, собранные артефакты - отдельно.

Очень странным решением кажется то, что вы копируете (чем?) ваш dll-файл в папку debug. Если уж вы не собираете свою dll на сборочном сервере в nuget-пакет, а подкладываете в проект - то есть более правильный путь. Создайте в solution папку lib, в которую положите dll. Это уже не папка debug, поэтому гит не будет против добавления файлов из этой папки в staging area. В вашем solution в нужных projects подключите библиотеку из папки lib и укажите в настройках файла, что его нужно всегда копировать в директорию где происходит сборка.

Так стоит настраивать проект, если вы не можете по каким-то причинам собрать свой dll в пакет.

На будущее рекомендую всё-таки потратить время и сделать более правильно: собрать nuget-пакет, не хранить их в исходниках и настроить nuget restore.